# Remove constexpr from C++14 template specialization?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, template-specialization, constexpr

The basic question is if it should be possible to add or remove constexpr from specialized template methods or not.

Let's assume the following code:

```
//this is my general vector template with a constexpr default ctor
template<typename T, typename STORE>
struct alignas(16) vec {
    union {
        STORE st;
        struct { T x; T y; T z; T w; };
    };

    inline explicit constexpr vec() noexcept :
        x{0}, y{0}, z{0}, w{0} {
    }
};

//and this is the SSE enabled version, where we cannot use
//constexpr because of _mm_setzero_ps, so let's remove it...
template<>
inline vec<float, __m128>::vec() noexcept :
    st(_mm_setzero_ps()) {
}
```

GCC has no problem compiling it, however clang complains that a "non-constexpr declaration of 'vec' follows constexpr declaration". I wonder which compiler does it right and why..? (I couldn't test MSVC so far)

EDIT: Because folks are very picky about copy and paste errors, I corrected the code so that it compiles.

Comment: As it stands, every compiler would have problems compiling that. Forgetting the syntax errors, MSVC also doesn't allow it. Explicitly specializing `vec` does allow you to write the non-constexpr constructor, though.

Comment: Looks like it's an even split between compilers: Clang and MSVC reject it, GCC and the EDG front end in strict mode accept it. I tend to think it should be rejected: it's an explicit specialization of a member of a class template, for an implicit instantiation of that template. The implicit instantiation of the class template involves instantiating the declarations of the member functions, so the `constexpr` is already there. There's a somewhat related example in the standard in [14.7.3p6] (involving `enum`s, but I think the principle is the same).

Comment: @JamesRoot The point was the removal of constexpr...

Comment: There's no real reason to use specialization here. Just [tag dispatch](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/300c1b3180372946) with a delegating constructor.

Comment: @T.C. Nice solution, a bit unfortunate that the SSE version cannot be separated into independent header (but not really an issue). Still I do wonder if it is correct.

Comment: @T.C. However I feel like doing the work of the compiler here (and having 3 method bodies instead of 2) and it is getting quite confusing if I add more specializations, eg. vec<double, __m128d[2]>.

Comment: @bogdan The fact that the tagging approach works should actually legalize the shown sample (since it is doing the same, just with a lot more typing).

Comment: Not quite. The tag dispatching solution doesn't change the fact that the default constructor is still constexpr in all instantiations of the template. For `vec<float, __m128>`, the instantiated default constructor definition doesn't satisfy the requirements for a constexpr constructor (it delegates to a non-constexpr one), so it can't appear in constant expressions, but it's still considered constexpr. This is allowed according to [7.1.5p6], as long as there is at least one other combination of template arguments for which the specialization does satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Note that there's an underlying reason for this apparent madness - see [CWG 1358](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1358). Also note that there are still wrinkles in the wording - [CWG 1872](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1872). I'm afraid it will take another couple of Standard iterations for the specification of constexpr and constant evaluation in general to be considered stable... I do agree that the pattern used in your example could be useful, but I think special wording would need to be added to the Standard to allow it.

Comment: Read both items and wonder in how far they are applicable in this particular case. Currently thinking about CRTP to do the same thing, then new template specializations are possible without modifications to the base and can be kept in separated easily (tagging makes that rather tricky).

Comment: For people downvoting the question please leave a comment. I think it is a real problem that we cannot decide if specialized template methods can use constexpr or not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be valid code as explained in a note inside 7.1.5 of the draft Standard [**N4567**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf)

> **7.1.5 The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr]**
>
> 1 The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable or
>   variable template, the declaration of a function or function template,
>   or the declaration of a static data member of a literal type (3.9). If
>   any declaration of a function or function template has a constexpr
>   specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the constexpr
>   specifier. [ Note: **An explicit specialization can differ from the
>   template declaration with respect to the constexpr specifier.** — end
>   note ] [ Note: Function parameters cannot be declared constexpr. — end
>   note ]

So gcc appears to be correct.

Comment: The problem here is that `vec<float, __m128>` is implicitly instantiated, which includes a declaration of `vec<float, __m128>::vec()` with the `constexpr` specifier, which would make the sentence right before the note apply. If `vec()` were a standalone function template, what happens here would be similar to first declaring (and not defining) an explicit specialization with `constexpr`, and later on providing a definition for that explicit specialization without `constexpr`. I'm not sure if we can rely on that note in this case.

Comment: @bogdan [temp.spec]/4 does not make the distinction between implicit and explicit instantiations when defining what an explicit specialization is, so why would that matter wrt to the note in [dcl.constexpr]/1?

Comment: That paragraph doesn't define what an explicit specialization is, it defines what a specialization is. Anyway, I don't think there's any distinction to make there. I think a relevant example is in [14.7.3p6]. Look at `A<char>::E`: even though it's defining an explicit specialization for a member, the member's definition instantiated when `A<char>` is implicitly instantiated is not ignored, and makes the code ill-formed. I think the declaration of `vec()` should be treated similarly.

Comment: The comment in [CWG 1792](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1792) reinforces that idea, I think, as it also refers to the declaration of the scoped `enum` `A<char>::S`, for which only a declaration is implicitly instantiated as part of the implicit instantiation of `A<char>`, just like for member functions.

Comment: Actually the note exactly describes this scenario, doesn't it?